# Why is my code resulting in a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, arrays

The tasks are the following:

/* LAB 6 TASK A*/

/*
  Save the entire array ia into a file called 'filename' in a binary
  file format that can be loaded by intarr_load_binary(). Returns
  zero on success, or a non-zero error code on failure. Arrays of
  length 0 should produce an output file containing an empty array.
*/

/* LAB 6 TASK B*/

/*
  Load a new array from the file called 'filename', that was
  previously saved using intarr_save_binary(). Returns a pointer to a
  newly-allocated intarr_t on success, or NULL on failure.
*/

For A, my code is the following:

```
int intarr_save_binary( intarr_t* ia, const char* filename )
{
    int returnValue = 0;
    unsigned int len = ia->len;
    FILE *f;

    if( NULL == (f = fopen (filename, "wb") ))
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        returnValue = 1;
    }

    else if ( fwrite ( &len, sizeof(int), 1, f) == 1 )
    { // then write of length successful

        if (fwrite (ia->data, sizeof(int), len, f) == len)
        {
            returnValue = 0; // indicate success
        }

        else
        { // else, write of data failed
            returnValue = 3;
        }
    }
    else
    { // else, failed to write len value to file
        returnValue = 4;
    }

    fclose( f ); // cleanup (writes last buffer to file)
    return( returnValue );
}
```

And for B, my code is the following:

```
intarr_t* intarr_load_binary( const char* filename )
{
    unsigned int len = 0;
    FILE *f = NULL;
    intarr_t* newia = NULL;

    if( NULL == fopen (filename, "rb") )
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // end if

    // implied else, fopen successful

    if( NULL == (newia = malloc (sizeof(intarr_t)))){
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        fclose(f);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // end if

    // implied else, malloc successful

    if( (fread (&len, sizeof(int), 1, f) != 1 ) )
    { // then fread failed
        perror( "fread failed" );
        fclose(f);
        free( newia );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // end if

    // implied else, fread for len successful

    newia->len = len;

    if( NULL == (newia->data = malloc (len*sizeof(int)) ) )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        fclose(f);
        free( newia );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // end if

    // implied else, malloc successful

    if( fread( newia->data, sizeof(int), len, f ) != len )
    { // then, fread failed
        perror( "fread failed" );
        fclose(f);
        free(newia->data);
        free(newia);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // end if

    // implied else, fread successful

    fclose (f);
    return newia;
}  // end function: intarr_load_binary
```

Can anyone please tell me why my code results in a segmentation fault? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In the code for B, `NULL` is passed to `fread()` in the line

```
if( (fread (&len, sizeof(int), 1, f) != 1 ) )
```

so it may lead to Segmentation Fault.

To fix this, assign the file pointer returned from `fopen()` to `f`:
Change

```
if( NULL == fopen (filename, "rb") )
```

to

```
if( NULL == (f = fopen (filename, "rb")) )
```

Also check if the parameters passed to the functions are valid.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have submitted my code and will let you know of the results. Again, I am truly grateful that you helped me! You are awesome!

Comment: This is the error message: 
Testing Corner cases
 intarr_save_binary( NULL, "foo" );
  *** SEGMENTATION FAULT ***

Comment: What do you think the problem is?

Comment: @J.Khelly The problem is not checking if `ia` is `NULL` before dereferencing it.

Comment: I am a beginner in C. Therefore, I am not too sure what you mean by that haha. Would you mind explaining a bit further?